# how to do the Expand & Collapse functionality for records in table

Tags: apex, visualforce

[image]

i want to display the Expand & Collapse functionality for this table

Comment: Easier would be to do in JavaScript or jQuery. Could you share your code, for us to know what you have tried so far?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use below Apex/VF Code for reference:

----------------------------------Script-------------------------------------

```
<script>
            var $x = jQuery.noConflict();
        function toggleDateTable(index){     
            //alert('--1--'+index)  
            var signtext = $x("#date-sign-"+index).text();
            var firstIndex = index;

            if(signtext == '+'){
                $x("#date-sign-"+index).text('-');
                $x(".toshow"+index).removeClass("tohide");
            }
            else{
                $x("#date-sign-"+index).text('+');
                $x(".toshow"+index).addClass("tohide");
            }
        }
    </script> 

-------------------Apex Table ------------------------------------

<apex:pageBlock id="pb1" title="">
                                <apex:variable value="{!0}" var="dateIndex" id="incrrvar"/>
                                <apex:variable value="{!0}" var="count"/>
                                <table class="tableClass" style="top:-70px;position:relative;">

                                <tr style="background:#CCCCFF;height: 36px;" class="tableheader">
                                    <th width="2%" class="leftAlign">
                                        Action
                                    </th>
                                    <th width="12%" class="leftAlign">
                                        Opportunity Name
                                    </th>
                                    <th width="5%" class="leftAlign">
                                        Opportunity Id
                                    </th>
                                    <th  width="12%" class="leftAlign">
                                        Account Name
                                    </th>
                                    <th width="5%" class="leftAlign">
                                        Stage
                                    </th>
                                    <th width="6%" class="leftAlign">
                                        Deal TCV$
                                    </th>
                                    <th width="6%" class="leftAlign">
                                        Close Date
                                    </th>
                                    <th width="5%" class="leftAlign">
                                        Deal Duration
                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                                <apex:repeat value="{!oppParentToChildMap}" var="dateKey" id="dateTable" >
                                    <tr class="{!IF(count==0,'lightBG', 'darkBG')}">
                                        <td width="2%" style="text-align:center;">
                                            <span id="date-sign-{!dateIndex}" class="sign-class " onclick="toggleDateTable('{!dateIndex}');" style="display:{!IF(parentOppToChildCount[dateKey]>0,'block', 'none')}">
                                                +
                                            </span>
                                            <span class="sign-class " style="display:{!IF(parentOppToChildCount[dateKey]==0,'block', 'none')}">
                                                &nbsp;
                                            </span>
                                        </td>
                                        <td width="12%" class="leftAlign">
                                           <apex:outputLink value="/{!parentOppMap[dateKey].Id}" target="_blank">{!parentOppMap[dateKey].Name}</apex:outputLink>
                                        </td>
                                        <td width="5%" class="leftAlign">
                                            <apex:outputText value="{!parentOppMap[dateKey].OpportunityID}"/>
                                        </td>
                                        <td width="12%" class="leftAlign">
                                            <apex:outputLink value="/{!parentOppMap[dateKey].AccountId}" target="_blank">{!parentOppMap[dateKey].Account.Name}</apex:outputLink>
                                        </td>
                                        <td width="5%" class="leftAlign">
                                            <apex:outputText value="{!parentOppMap[dateKey].StageName}"/>
                                        </td>
                                        <td width="6%" class="leftAlign">
                                            <apex:outputText value="USD{0, number, ###,###}">
                                                <apex:param value="{!parentOppMap[dateKey].Vertical_TCV__c}" /> 
                                            </apex:outputText>
                                        </td>
                                        <td width="6%" class="leftAlign">
                                            <apex:outputText value="{0, date, MM'/'dd'/'yyyy}">
                                                <apex:param value="{!parentOppMap[dateKey].CloseDate}" /> 
                                            </apex:outputText>
                                        </td>
                                        <td width="5%" class="leftAlign">
                                            <apex:outputText value="{0, number, ######}">
                                                <apex:param value="{!parentOppMap[dateKey].Deal_Duration__c}" /> 
                                            </apex:outputText>
                                        </td>

                                    </tr>
                                    <apex:repeat value="{!oppParentToChildMap[dateKey]}" var="stageKey" id="stageTable">
                                        <tr class="tohide toshow{!dateIndex} {!IF(count==0,'lightBG', 'darkBG')}">
                                            <td class="lightBG"> 
                                            <span class="sign-class " >
                                                &nbsp;
                                            </span>
                                            </td>
                                            <td width="15%" class="leftAlign">
                                                <!--<apex:outputText value="{!stageKey.Name}"/>-->
                                                <apex:outputLink value="/{!stageKey.Id}" target="_blank">{!stageKey.Name}</apex:outputLink>
                                            </td>
                                            <td width="5%" class="leftAlign">
                                                <apex:outputText value="{!stageKey.OpportunityID}"/>
                                            </td>
                                            <td width="10%" class="leftAlign">
                                                <!--<apex:outputText value="{!stageKey.Account.Name}"/>-->
                                                <apex:outputLink value="/{!stageKey.AccountId}" target="_blank">{!stageKey.Account.Name}</apex:outputLink>
                                            </td>
                                            <td width="5%" class="leftAlign">
                                                <apex:outputText value="{!stageKey.StageName}"/>
                                            </td>
                                            <td width="6%" class="leftAlign">
                                                <apex:outputText value="USD{0, number, ###,###}">
                                                    <apex:param value="{!stageKey.Vertical_TCV__c}" /> 
                                                </apex:outputText>
                                            </td>
                                            <td width="6%" class="leftAlign">
                                                <apex:outputText value="{0, date, MM'/'dd'/'yyyy}">
                                                    <apex:param value="{!stageKey.CloseDate}" /> 
                                                </apex:outputText>
                                            </td>
                                            <td width="5%" class="leftAlign">
                                                <apex:outputText value="{0, number, ######}">
                                                    <apex:param value="{!stageKey.Deal_Duration__c}" /> 
                                                </apex:outputText>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </apex:repeat>
                                    <apex:variable value="{!dateIndex+1}" var="dateIndex" id="incrrvar"/>
                                    <apex:variable value="{!IF(count==0,count+1,0)}" var="count"/>
                                </apex:repeat>    
                            </table>  
                            <apex:outputText value="{!$Label.ErrorMsg_rnwDash}" rendered="{!!recordsFound}" style="color:red;font-weight:bold;"></apex:outputText>                              
                            </apex:pageBlock>
```

----------------------Apex code-----------------------------------

public void myOpportunityDetails(){
        oppParentToChildMap = new Map>();
        parentOppMap = new Map();
        parentOppToChildCount = new Map();
        recordsFound = false;

```
    for(Opportunity opp : [SELECT Name, Account.Name,AccountID, Vertical_TCV__c, StageName, CloseDate,Deal_Duration__c,Parent_Opportunity__c, OpportunityID, Opportunity_Order__c, Id FROM Opportunity where IsClosed = false AND Type = 'Big Deals' AND CloseDate <> null AND OwnerId = :UserInfo.getUserId() order by Parent_Opportunity__c, Opportunity_Order__c])     
    {       

            recordsFound = true;        

        if(opp.Parent_Opportunity__c == null)       
        {       
            oppParentToChildMap.put(String.valueOf(opp.OpportunityID), new List<Opportunity>());       
            parentOppMap.put(String.valueOf(opp.OpportunityID), opp);      
            parentOppToChildCount.put(String.valueOf(opp.OpportunityID), 0);       
        }       
        else        
        {       
            if(oppParentToChildMap.containsKey(String.valueOf(opp.Parent_Opportunity__c)))      
            {       
                oppParentToChildMap.get(String.valueof(opp.Parent_Opportunity__c)).add(opp);        
                parentOppToChildCount.put(String.valueOf(opp.Parent_Opportunity__c), parentOppToChildCount.get(String.valueOf(opp.Parent_Opportunity__c)) + 1);     
            }       
            else        
            {       
                oppParentToChildMap.put(String.valueOf(opp.Parent_Opportunity__c), new List<Opportunity>());        
                parentOppMap.put(String.valueOf(opp.Parent_Opportunity__c), opp);       
                parentOppToChildCount.put(String.valueOf(opp.Parent_Opportunity__c), 0);        
            }       
        }       
    }       
}
```